# Request to onedrive permission returning wrong information

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/invite

**Request Body:**

```js
{
    "recipients":[{"email":"some_valid@ID.com"}],
    "message":"",
    "requireSignIn":true,
    "sendInvitation":false,
    "roles":["write"]
}
```

**Response Body:**

```js
{
    "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)",
    "value":[{
        "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.permission",
        "grantedTo":{"user":{"displayName":"some_valid@ID.com"}},
        "id":"<PERMISSION_ID>",
        "roles":["write"]
    }]
}
```

I'm getting proper response with 200 ("OK") status code. But I'm not able to access the sharepoint folder with "some_valid@ID.com" account. Also when I'm checking the permissions on the folder in the sharepoint, the "some_valid@ID.com" id is not listed in manage access list.

Comment: are you sharing with an external user?

Comment: Yes, it was an external user and an outlook account.

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of 'By Design' and a bug. The 'By Design' part is that if you choose to not send the email invite, the user will not be able to access the document. The user typically needs to redeem the link in the invite before they get access. The bug is that the API response should still show that the user was granted access(although the invitation never got sent out, the invitation link however could be shared at a later time) . We are working on a fix. Thanks for bringing it up.